# Leetcode 374 - Confused about this difference between solutions

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Can someone explain between the two solutions.

Incorrect:

```
        int l = 1;
        int h = n;

        while(l<=h){

            int mid = l+(h-l)/2;

            if (guess(mid) == -1){
                l = mid+1;
            }
            else if (guess(mid) == 1){
                h = mid-1;
            }
            else if (guess(mid) == 0){
                return mid;
            }
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

I initially just returned mid in an else{} but that did not seem to work either and can't see how those solutions would actually be any different.

Correct:

```
        int low = 1;
        int high = n;
        
        while(low<=high){
            int mid = low+(high-low)/2;
            if(guess(mid)==0){
                return mid;
            } else if(guess(mid)==1){
                low = mid+1;
            } else{
                high = mid-1;
            }
        }
        
        return low;
    }
```

Comment: When asking code-related questions, you need to provide both a tag for the language you're using, and an [mre] that demonstrates the issue. You've not provided any language tag, and have provided two incomplete, syntactically incorrect code snippets. Please [edit] your post to ask properly, so that we can try to help.

Answer (score 2):

You have given opposite logic when guess(num) returns 1 or -1

in your given correct solution

```
if(guess(mid)==1){
   low = mid+1;
}
```

So i guess, when guess method returns 1, your guessed number is less than the actual number and **low** value should increase. But you are doing the opposite.